# Sony DSC-HX200V is right choice for Beginner?

Tags: digital, sony, photography-basics

I am newbie with the photography, and just wanted to start it.

I have purchased [Sony DSC-HX200V](http://www.sony.co.in/product/dsc-hx200v) to get started with. I would like to know I have made right choice or not? And what I can get/expect from this camera.??

Comment: Are you aware of the phrase "Closing the stable door after the horse has bolted"? :)

Comment: I think the question isn't really a good fit for the site, but I will note that the gear is only a part of the equation. It's your eye that matters the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already bought that camera I suggest you use it.

The good news is that optics and physics don't really care about brands and models so photography basics are exactly the same for all cameras from the crappiest cellphone to the most expensive DSLR and behind.

So use the camera you got, take lots of pictures - and when there's a specific photo you can't take with your current gear then it's time to ask how to take that photo.